# How to calculate maximum/minimum number of probes required to build a hash-table

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

I'm currently working with Algorithms Fourth Edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne and I'm stuck on one of the exercises. I know that there's someone who's posted the solutions to many of the exercises from this book on GitHub, but I want to do them on my own so that I can understand and learn from them.

I've been scanning the book for how to calculate the maximum/minimum number of probes required to build a hash-table (exercise 3.4.12), but I can't find any methods/functions/formulas which shows how to move forward when dealing with such a problem.

The exercise:

> Suppose that the keys A through G, with the hash values given below, are inserted in some order into an initially empty table of size 7 (= m) using a linear-probing (when there's a collision ew just check the next entry in the table by incrementing index) table (with no resizing for this problem)
>
> key  = "A B C D E F G"
>
> hash = "2 0 0 4 4 4 2"
>
> Which of the following could not possibly result from inserting these keys?
>
> a)  E F G A C B D
>
> b)  C E B G F D A
>
> c)  B D F A C E G
>
> d)  C G B A D E F
>
> e)  F G B D A C E
>
> f)  G E C A D B F

I found this website http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book2/algo02e5.htm , but I couldn't understand much of it. I got stumped on what to do when I tried to solve this, first I thought I had misunderstood the question, or that I simply couldn't find the formula on how to solve the exercise.

How do I calculate the maximum and minimum number of probes that could be required to build a table of size m?

Comment: This is a theory question and not a programming question, so it should go to https://cs.stackexchange.com/ where you may get answers in line with what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific formula for this question.
You need to look at each order, and decide whether that order is possible to achieve.

Let's look at (a) together: `E F G A C B D`.

If we replace the keys with their hash values, we'll get `4 4 2 2 0 0 4`. Now the important part - note that **only** `G` is located in "right" bucket, all other values have been shifted due to the linear probing. Is that possible?

Say we've inserted G first and it was written to index 2. What now? If we insert a key with hash `0` or `4`, it will be placed in cell `0` or `4` without probing, which is not what we want. The only option is to insert `A` now, which also has a hash value of `2`. Where will it go? Index 3 of course due to the linear probing. So far, so good, our array looks like this: `X X G A X X X`

What now? We're left only with keys whose hash is `0` or `4`, and once we insert one such key, it will be placed in cell `0` or `4`. But in the pattern we're being aseked about, all values with hashes `0` and `4` aren't in the "right" cell. Therefore, this pattern is not possible.

Now let's look at (b). The order is `C E B G F D A` which translates to `0 4 0 2 4 4 2`. How can we create this pattern?

Let's insert C: `C X X X X X X`
What now? Let's insert F: `C X X X F X X`. Now let's insert D. Due to linear probing, we'll end up with `C X X X F D X`. What now? We're stuck. It doesn't matter what we insert now, we won't be able to reach `C E B G F D A`. Is there anything we can change about our previous inserts to achieve a different result? No. Therefore, (b) is also impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like non of the choices are possible.

a) E F G A C B D (4 4 **2 2** 0 0 4) .
possible insertion order : G,A (the rest is not possible)

b) C E B G F D A (**0** 4 0 2 **4 4** 2) .
possible insertion order : C, F, D (the rest is not possible)

c) B D F A C E G (**0** 4 4 2 0 4 2) .
possible insertion order : B (the rest is not possible)

d) C G B A D E F (**0** 2 0 2 **4 4 4**) .
possible insertion order : C, D, E, F (the rest is not possible)

e) F G B D A C E (4 2 0 4 2 0 4) .
possible insertion order : no possible insertion sequence

f) G E C A D B F (2 4 0 2 **4** 0 4) .
possible insertion order : D (the rest is not possible)